# test if before set cellule in phpexcelBundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I use phpexcelBundle for export database to file excel but i have problem when I use attribut in databsae is null ,I have problem of export file excel ,I have problem attribut is null but when i use if before set cellule I have problem of export also
this is problem :

> [:error] [pid 2684] [client ::1:33360] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$phpExcelObject' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /var/www/html/Projetsf/src/FrontBundle/Controller/StepsController.php on line 10000, referer:

this is code controller :

```
public function exportXLSAction($id){

         $phpExcelObject = new PHPExcel();
          $phpExcelObject->getProperties()->setCreator("liuggio")
           ->setLastModifiedBy("Giulio De Donato")
           ->setTitle("Office 2005 XLSX Test Document")
           ->setSubject("Office 2005 XLSX Test Document")
           ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2005 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
           ->setKeywords("office 2005 openxml php")
           ->setCategory("Test result file");
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager($this->container->get('account_manager')->getCurrentAccount()->getEmname());
    $Employee= $em->getRepository('FrontBundle:Employee')->findOneBy(array('id' =>$id));


     if ($Employee->getNom() != null) { $x = $Employee->getNom(); } else  { $x = ' '; }
       $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A1', 'Civilité')
                ->setCellValue('A2', $Employee->getCivilite())
                ->setCellValue('B1','Nom')
                ->setCellValue('B2', $x)
                ->setCellValue('C1', 'Prénom')
                ->setCellValue('C2', $Employee->getPrenom())
                ->setCellValue('D1', 'Email Personnel')
                ->setCellValue('D2', $Employee->getEmail())
               ->setCellValue('E1', 'Adresse Personnel')
                ->setCellValue('E2', $Employee->getAdresse()) ;


              foreach(range('A','Z') as $columnID){
     }
     }
     $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setAutoSize(true);
}
 foreach(range('A','Z') as $columnID){
     $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getColumnDimension('A'.$columnID)->setAutoSize(true);
}


$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($phpExcelObject);
$nomfichier = $Employee->getPrenom().'.xlsx';
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$nomfichier.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter->save('php://output'); 


     // var_dump($response);
       return new response('yes');
             }
```

problem in test if $employee->getnom()!= null ... but i have make this test

help me for resolve this problem and thanks advanced

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a typo in this block of statement?

```
              foreach(range('A','Z') as $columnID){
     }  // WHY?
     } // WHY?
     $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setAutoSize(true);
}
```

Try removing them, as example something like:

```
    foreach(range('A','Z') as $columnID){
    $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setAutoSize(true);
    }

    foreach(range('A','Z') as $columnID){
$phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getColumnDimension('A'.$columnID)->setAutoSize(true);
    }
```

EDIT:

Try this code:

```
    public function exportXLSAction($id){

        $phpExcelObject = new \PHPExcel();
        $phpExcelObject->getProperties()->setCreator("liuggio")
            ->setLastModifiedBy("Giulio De Donato")
            ->setTitle("Office 2005 XLSX Test Document")
            ->setSubject("Office 2005 XLSX Test Document")
            ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2005 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
            ->setKeywords("office 2005 openxml php")
            ->setCategory("Test result file");
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager($this->container->get('account_manager')->getCurrentAccount()->getEmname());
        $Employee= $em->getRepository('FrontBundle:Employee')->findOneBy(array('id' =>$id));


        if ($Employee->getNom() != null) { $x = $Employee->getNom(); } else  { $x = ' '; }
        $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Civilité')
            ->setCellValue('A2', $Employee->getCivilite())
            ->setCellValue('B1','Nom')
            ->setCellValue('B2', $x)
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Prénom')
            ->setCellValue('C2', $Employee->getPrenom())
            ->setCellValue('D1', 'Email Personnel')
            ->setCellValue('D2', $Employee->getEmail())
            ->setCellValue('E1', 'Adresse Personnel')
            ->setCellValue('E2', $Employee->getAdresse()) ;


foreach(range('A','Z') as $columnID){
    $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getColumnDimension('A'.$columnID)->setAutoSize(true);
}


$objWriter = new \PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($phpExcelObject);
$nomfichier = $Employee->getPrenom().'.xlsx';
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$nomfichier.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter->save('php://output');


// var_dump($response);
return new response('yes');
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: also problem :(